# Apagar os comentários quando um chat é criado?

Tags: debate, comentários

Quando são feitos muitos comentários a uma resposta aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Por favor evite discussões extensas nos comentários. Gostaria de [mover
>   automaticamente esta discussão para o chat](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6170)?

Se eu clicar nesse link todos os comentários serão migrados. Mas sempre fiquei a questionar-me porque é que eles não são apagados do post.

Será que eles deveriam ser apagados automaticamente?

Comment: eu entendo de onde você vem - mas existem diversas implicações, por exemplo: outras pessoas que acessam a pergunta não saberiam que existe um chat debatendo a questão - ou poderiam começar a comentar nessa pergunta de novo, fazendo os mesmos questionamentos que já foram feitos anteriormente - fico achando que esta é uma maneira de resolver um problema causando três novos

Comment: @Blogueira Quando o chat é criado, um link é adicionado automáticamente nos comentários. Entao qualquer pessoa podia visitar o chat. Mas sim, nada impede doutros usuários criar mais comentários...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Será que eles deveriam ser apagados automaticamente?

Não, algumas vezes vários usuários tentam ajudar o OP então o número de comentários cresce rápido porém alguns são uteis (como link ou breves explicações) e não devem ser apagados automáticamente.

Quando **possível** entre no chat converse com OP para solucionar o problema, ao identificar o problema você pode atualizar a pergunta com o detalhe importante e adicionar o link do chat que confirma isso.